# Handling click event in bootstrap flip card

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I am using bootstrap as CSS framework for my web application.In my html page I have flip card control, in the back face I would like to place carousel to navigate some content,however, since the flip card flips when I click anywhere inside it; I am not able to navigate my content because any click to (previous/next) buttons in the carousel flips the card.

Is there any way to handle events in a tunneling manner; just like WPF ? or any other suggested solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered it ; I need to call

event.stopPropagation();

where "event" is the event argument

Comment: you can mark your answer as correct, if that's what worked for you.